# Creating a schedule via python

Tags: python

I'm currently working on trying to build a scheduler that will assign parts to specific time slots.  This is what I've come up with currently, but I'm curious to know if there is a better way to do this.  I'm fairly new to coding in python, so really have just working with while/for loops and if/else statements.  I'm sure there is a way, so hopefully someone out there can show me the light.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

day_start = str('2021-07-28 06:30')
break_1_start = str('2021-07-28 08:50')
lunch_start = str('2021-07-28 12:00')
break_2_start = str('2021-07-28 14:50')
day_end = str('2021-07-28 17:40')
day_start = datetime.strptime(day_start, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
break_1_start = datetime.strptime(break_1_start, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
break_1_end = break_1_start + timedelta(minutes=20)
lunch_start = datetime.strptime(lunch_start, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
lunch_end = lunch_start + timedelta(minutes=30)
break_2_start = datetime.strptime(break_2_start, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
break_2_end = break_2_start + timedelta(minutes=20)
day_end = datetime.strptime(day_end, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

sched_df = pd.DataFrame({"Time": [day_start, break_1_start, break_1_end, lunch_start, lunch_end,
                                  break_2_start, break_2_end, day_end]})

print(sched_df)

demand_df = pd.DataFrame({"PartNo": ['Part1', 'Part2', 'Part3', 'Part4', 'Part5'],
                          "TTJ": [75, 100, 180, 30, 60]})

demand_df = demand_df.astype({'TTJ': float})

print(demand_df)

a = 0
b = 1
c = 2
x = sched_df.iloc[a]['Time']
y = sched_df.iloc[0]['Time']
z = 0


for n in range(0, len(demand_df)):
    while y < sched_df.iloc[1]['Time']:
        y = x + timedelta(minutes=demand_df.iloc[a]['TTJ'])
        if y > sched_df.iloc[1]['Time']:
            end = sched_df.iloc[1]['Time']
            print(demand_df.iloc[a]['PartNo'], 'time from : ', x.time(), ' to ', end.time())
            start = sched_df.iloc[1]['Time']
            end = sched_df.iloc[2]['Time']
            print('Break time from : ', start.time(), ' to ', end.time())

            xyz = sched_df.iloc[1]['Time'] - x
            delta = xyz.total_seconds()
            minutes = float(delta // 60)
            z = demand_df.iloc[a]['TTJ'] - minutes

            x = end + timedelta(minutes=z)
            counter = a

        else:
            print(demand_df.iloc[a]['PartNo'], 'time from : ', x.time(), ' to ', y.time())
            x = y
            a = a+1

if x > sched_df.iloc[3]['Time']:
    start = sched_df.iloc[2]['Time']
    end = sched_df.iloc[3]['Time']
    print(demand_df.iloc[a]['PartNo'], 'time from : ', start.time(), ' to ', end.time())
    xyz = x-end
    delta = xyz.total_seconds()
    minutes = float(delta // 60)
    z = minutes

    start = sched_df.iloc[3]['Time']
    end = sched_df.iloc[4]['Time']
    print('Lunch time from : ', start.time(), ' to ', end.time())

    start = sched_df.iloc[4]['Time']
    x = start + timedelta(minutes=z)

    print(demand_df.iloc[a]['PartNo'], 'time from : ', start.time(), ' to ', x.time())
    z = 0
    a = a + 1
else:
    start = sched_df.iloc[2]['Time']
    print(demand_df.iloc[a]['PartNo'], 'time from : ', start.time(), ' to ', x.time())
    z = 0
    a = a + 1
    y = x
    for n in range(0, len(demand_df)):
        while y < sched_df.iloc[3]['Time']:
            y = x + timedelta(minutes=demand_df.iloc[a]['TTJ'])
            if y > sched_df.iloc[3]['Time']:
                end = sched_df.iloc[3]['Time']
                print(demand_df.iloc[a]['PartNo'], 'time from : ', x.time(), ' to ', end.time())
                start = sched_df.iloc[3]['Time']
                end = sched_df.iloc[4]['Time']
                print('Lunch time from : ', start.time(), ' to ', end.time())

                xyz = sched_df.iloc[3]['Time'] - x
                delta = xyz.total_seconds()
                minutes = float(delta // 60)
                z = demand_df.iloc[a]['TTJ'] - minutes

                start = sched_df.iloc[4]['Time']
                x = start + timedelta(minutes=z)

                print(demand_df.iloc[a]['PartNo'], 'time from : ', start.time(), ' to ', x.time())
                z = 0
                a = a + 1

            else:
                print(demand_df.iloc[a]['PartNo'], 'time from : ', x.time(), ' to ', y.time())
                x = y
                a = a + 1
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What about the breaks are you having trouble with?  What have you tried?

Comment: @ChrisMarotta Basically trying to figure out if I start the next part say Part C at 8:30 and its supposed to take 60 minutes, how do I get up to break at 8:50 return back at 9:10 and add the remainder of the time to 9:10.  Should be 9:50

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly your problem is, but if you say you are new to python programming you could read through some comparable projects.

A project that comes to my mind would be [pyschedule](https://github.com/timnon/pyschedule) for example. The solution approaches should be similar to those to your problem.

Comment: I've basically have a list of employees, parts, and how long each employee should work on each part.  I'm trying to figure out a way to read in this list and schedule that day accordingly for each employee.  For example, Employee A needs to work on parts, A, B, and C.  Part A takes him 100 minutes, Part B takes him 150 minutes, and part C takes 200 minutes.  The work schedule is 6:30-17:30.  There is a 20 minute break at 9:00 and 14:00, and 30 minute lunch at 12:00.